# how to assign session data in class property in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set session data to class property in Laravel controller but getting null in controller functions please help me with how to deal with that or suggest me best approach for that.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;

class InventoryController extends Controller
{
    public $company_id;
    public function __construct()
    {   
        $company_id = session('last_company');
        $this->company_id = $company_id;
    }
    public function index()
    {
        dd($this->company_id);
        $products = Product::where('company_id',$this->company_id)->get();
        // dd($products);
        return view('Inventory.view',compact($products));
    }
}
```

Im getting **$this->company_id** as **null** in index function
but i can get data when **dd(session('last_company'))** in index function

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;

class InventoryController extends Controller
{
    public $company_id;
    public function __construct()
    {   
        $company_id = session('last_company');
        $this->company_id = $company_id;
    }
    public function index()
    {
        dd(session('last_company'));
        $products = Product::where('company_id',session('last_company'))->get();
        return view('Inventory.view',compact($products));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to indicate which line is causing the `null` error.

Comment: @Peppermintology sure

Comment: That suggests your `session('last_company');` value is not what you expect.

Comment: @Peppermintology I do get data in session('last_company') when I use it directly in fuction.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get `null` is that the session manager, `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession` is a middleware and it's not bootstrapped at that point. Furthermore, there is no reason to keep session data in a controller because the controller's `__destruct` method will be called by the time you return the response back to the route's chain. You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/lifecycle). Instead of that, you can try this,

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::where('company_id', $request->session()->get('company_id')->get();
    return view('Inventory.view',compact($products));
}
```

You may want to pass a default value to second argument of `get` method to be returned if the specified value does not exist.